# How to ignore directories when running Django collectstatic?

Tags: python, django, deployment

I am running a small test project with Django 1.3, Ubuntu 11.10, gunicorn and Nginx, everything in a virtualenv, and now I'm running collectstatic to get my static files into the directory that Nginx serves from.

For simplicity's sake let's say my static directory is something like /home/user/static and my project is at /home/user/project

When I go to /home/user/project I run:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
```

and it correctly copies static files from all the apps I have installed. Unfortunately this also copies the files from Django's admin and I would like to skip that one.

I checked the documentation for collecstatic and there´s an -i (--ignore) parameter that takes a glob-style parameter so I tried different variations of the command, as I´m not sure if the ignore pattern refers to my /home/user/static or to the original app directory.

Here some examples that didn´t work:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i /home/user/static/admin
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i /home/user/static/admin/*
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i /home/user/static/a*
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i /home/alexis/.virtualenvs/django13/*
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i /home/user/.virtualenvs/django13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin*
```

I found that if I create a symbolic link from /home/user/static/admin to /home/user/.virtualenvs/django13/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media collectstatic will notice and skip copying those files again but anyway, I´d like to make the --ignore option work as it should.

What am I missing?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you manage to make any progress?

Answer (score 44):

Don't write full path of directories. For example usage:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i admin
```

This command won't copy the admin/ directory to STATIC_ROOT path.

Comment: Suppose we have to ignore files of a certain type so would the following work
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i *.styl
where the files I want to be ignored have extension .styl?

Comment: Yes. Example:

    python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i *.sass

Comment: How would I add multiple ignores? eg, ignore anything with `admin` in the path *and* any `*.scss` files?

Comment: `manage.py help collectstatic` says: `-i PATTERN, --ignore=PATTERN
  Ignore files or directories matching this glob-style pattern. Use multiple times to ignore more.` so @PhilGyford you would use something like: `-i admin -i *.scss`

Answer (score 12):

The [Django 2.2 release](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.2/#django-contrib-staticfiles) has finally addressed the very longstanding issue of specifying ignore parameters with path matching, for example

```
manage.py collectstatic --ignore /vendor/*.js
```

should then work.

Comment: Can I specify a file that contains ignores like .gitignore or .gcloudignore?

Comment: no, you have to explicitly list the files to ignore -- but you could create a script to convert

Comment: Then it is probably better to write some bash script that will run ./manage.py with all needed ignores.

Answer (score -1):

I have a folder structure like this:

```
my_project
└─content
| └─static
|   └─content
|     ├─css
|     ├─dist
|     ├─js
|     ├─scss
```

I want to exclude the `scss` folder and all files in it.

I document all the things I tried below.

Here are the commands that **DON'T** work:

```
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore /content/static/content/scss"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore /content/static/content/scss/"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore /content/static/content/scss/*"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore content/static/content/scss"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore content/static/content/scss/"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore content/static/content/scss/*"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore /content/scss"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore /content/scss/"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore /content/scss/*"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore content/scss"
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore content/scss/"
```

Here are the commands that **DO** work:

```
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore content/scss/*" <- best
"python manage.py collectstatic --no-input --ignore content/scss*"
```

The absolute key to understanding this is to read this ten times:

> You need to find the path from static directories, not project
> root.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55679874/1577947)

The take-away is:

- you don't need a leading forward slash at the start of the path
- the path is relative from your static directories