# collectstatic doesn't ignore specified files

Tags: django

i'm having some trouble figuring out how to manage my scss files. Here's what my folder structure looks like:

```
 manage.py
├── myWebsite
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── projects
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   │   └── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   │   └── projects
│   │       └── css
│   │           ├── index.css
│   │           ├── scss
│   │           │   └── survey.scss
│   │           └── tribute.css
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── projects
│   │       ├── base.html
│   │       ├── documentation.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       ├── portfolio.html
│   │       ├── product.html
│   │       ├── survey.html
│   │       └── tribute.html
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── requirements.txt
└── staticfiles
    └── projects
        └── css
            └── scss
                ├── survey.css
                └── survey.css.map
```

I'd like to keep my .scss files inside the static/{app_name}/css/scss folder of each app. Those are later compiled inside the staticfiles folder which is in the project root. That same folder is the root for collectstatic, which is run when deploying on the server (AWS EB)

```
 02_collectstatic:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py collectstatic --noinput"
```

Since I'm using Django 2.2 it should be possible to ignore .scss files to be collected by collectstatic but doesn't seem to be working, I tried:

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i projects/static/projects/css/scss
```

EDIT: this is the kind of error I get:

```
Activity execution failed, because: usage: manage.py collectstatic [-h] [--noinput] [--no-post-process]
  [-i PATTERN] [-n] [-c] [-l]
  [--no-default-ignore] [--version]
  [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS]
  [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback]
  [--no-color] [--force-color]
  manage.py collectstatic: error: unrecognized arguments: /projects/static/projects/css/scss
   (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
```

Comment: can you share your `STATICFILES_DIRS` settings please?

Comment: I didn't specify any, it's using the default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are pointing to the wrong path when you are using `-i`. You need to find the path from static directory root, not project root. For example if your static directory is:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(APPS_DIR, "static"),  # where projects is the apps directory
]
# OR if you are using django-cookie-cutter
# STATICFILES_DIRS = [str(APPS_DIR.path("static"))]
```

Then, update the code like this:

```
 python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i projects/css/scss
```

Comment: Thank you, for some reason I didn't realize that the path for collectstatic was relative to the finders and not to the project, even though it may seem obvious

Answer (score 0):

Following Django 2.2 [Release Notes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/2.2/#django-contrib-staticfiles),

> Added path matching to the collectstatic `--ignore` option so that patterns like `/vendor/*.js` can be used.

```
python manage.py collectstatic --noinput --ignore /projects/static/projects/css/scss
```

Comment: It doesn't work, I added the error message from the AWS EB logs in the main post